# How to find ideals?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R=\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ be the ring (standard one) of continuous functions. For each $\gamma\in[0,1]$, let $I_\gamma=\{f\in R; f(\gamma)=0\}$. It is easy to prove that $I_\gamma$ is an ideal, in fact, a maximal one.

My question is: how to find other ideals (not necessarily maximal), that is, different of the type of $I_\gamma$?

Comment: Let $A\subseteq[0,1]$ be arbitrary, and let $I_A=\{f\in R:f(a)=0\text{ for all }a\in A\}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, thanks fot the suggestion, but your ideal is made with the same idea, that is, functions that vanishes. I am looking for some different types of ideals.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, sorry, but I have to read many answers to my questions, and they are not so trivial. So I need time to accept them.

Comment: The answers at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35793/prime-ideals-in-c0-1 might prove helpful. Good luck!

Comment: @FortuonPaendrag, thanks so much. Good link. For sure I'll learn a lot with it.

Comment: Well, ideals can be defined as kernels of ring homomorphisms. And this being a function ring, these are the obvious ring homomorphisms to the product rings.

Answer (score 3):

An intersection of two different maximal ideals cannot, of course, be maximal. After a little thought you can see how this ideal is described by using the same idea as the maximal ideals, except the zero sets have been merged, and now you're looking at the functions zero on two specific points.

From here you can go whole hog and use *any* subset of the interval as a zero set. Be aware though that these zero sets don't correspond to the ideals in a one-to-one way. Suppose for example, you use the subset of rationals of that interval as a zero set. Can you compute the corresponding ideal for me?

Another interesting fact about the ring you described (I hope my memory isn't wrong!) is that *all* the maximal ideals appear that way. I think this fact is false if the interval is unbounded, though!

Comment: Thanks. Would be possible to find ideals which are described by other rules than that ones using zeros of functions? I will try something. Thanks again. 

ps: your last statement is really nice.

Comment: If the interval is unbounded (or, equivalently, open in at least one end), then we can consider the ideal consisting of all functions that are zero outside some set of finite measure. By Zorn's lemma, this can be extended to a maximal ideal, but that maximal ideal cannot be an $I_\gamma$.

Comment: Generally, the domain needs to be compact, for all maximal ideals to arise this way.

Answer (score 2):

For $f\in R$ let $Z(f)=\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)=0\}$, the zero-set of $f$. A family $\mathscr{F}$ of zero-sets of $[0,1]$ is a zero-set filter if

- $\varnothing\notin\mathscr{F}$,
- $\mathscr{F}$ is closed under finite intersections, and
- $Z\in\mathscr{F}$ whenever $Z$ is a zero-set and $Z\supseteq Z_0$ for some $Z_0\in\mathscr{F}$.

Suppose that $I$ is an ideal in $R$. If $F$ is a finite subset of $I$ such that $\bigcap_{f\in F}Z(f)=\varnothing$, let $g=\sum_{f\in F}f^2$; then $Z(g)=\bigcap_{f\in F}Z(f)=\varnothing$, so $1/g\in R$, and $1_R\in I=R$. Thus, for a proper ideal $I$ the family $\mathscr{F}=\{Z(f):f\in I\}$ is closed under finite intersections and does not contain $\varnothing$. Now suppose that $Z$ is a zero-set of $[0,1]$ such that $Z\supseteq Z(f)$ for some $f\in I$. Let $g\in R$ be such that $Z(g)=Z$; then $fg\in I$ and $Z(fg)=Z$, so $Z\in\mathscr{F}$. That is, $\mathscr{F}$ is a zero-set filter on $[0,1]$.

Conversely, suppose that $\mathscr{F}$ is a zero-set filter on $[0,1]$ and let $I=\{f\in R:Z(f)\in\mathscr{F}\}$; then $I$ is an ideal of $R$.

- If $f,g\in I$, then $Z(f-g)\subseteq Z(f)\cap Z(g)\in\mathscr{F}$, so $f-g\in I$.
- If $f\in I$ and $g\in R$, then $Z(fg)=Z(f)\cup Z(g)\supseteq Z(f)$, so $g\in I$, and $RI\subseteq I$. (In fact $RI=I$, since $R$ has a multiplicative identity.) Let $Z=\bigcap\mathscr{F}$; $[0,1]$ is compact, so $Z\ne\varnothing$, and $I\subseteq I_Z=\{f\in R:Z(f)\supseteq Z\}$. However, $I$ may be a proper subset of $I_Z$. For example, fix a zero-set $Z\subsetneqq[0,1]$, let $\mathscr{Z}=\{Z_n:n\in\omega\}$ be a family of zero-sets such that $$Z_0\supseteq\operatorname{int}Z_0\supseteq Z_1\operatorname{int}Z_1\supseteq Z_1\supseteq\ldots\supseteq Z\;,$$ and let $\mathscr{F}$ be the zero-set filter generated by $\mathscr{Z}$, and let $I$ be the associated ideal. Let $f$ be any member of $R$ such that $Z(f)=Z$; then $f\in I_Z\setminus I$.

Comment: It would be interesting if these two operations (from ideals to filters and vice versa) could be shown to be inverses. :-)

Comment: ... but I don't think they can, because $(x^2)\subsetneq (x)$ yet both seem to have the same zero-set filter. (Perhaps filters determine _prime_ ideals?)

Comment: Can you please suggest a reference for the terminology (zero-set filter) you use? And indeed an enlightening answer.

Comment: @wentaway: It's a straightforward combination of standard terminology -- they are (proper) [filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28mathematics%29) in the lattice of all zero-sets ordered by set inclusion.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you. I have heard of but have not learnt about these filters. Thanks for the link too. I'll take a look.

Comment: @wentaway: The classic reference is Gillman & Jerison, [*Rings of Continuous Functions*](http://www.amazon.com/Rings-Continuous-Functions-L-Gillman/dp/0387901205).

Answer (score 1):

As rschwieb describes, you can take any $A\subseteq [0,1]$ and consider the ideal $I_A=\bigl\{f\in R\mid f(A)=\{0\}\bigr\}$. There may be several different $A$s that give rise to the same ideal in this way, but unless I'm mistaken, every such ideal is produced by exactly one *closed* $A$.

On the other hand, there are also ideals that are not produced in this way. One example is the set of all functions that are zero on some neighborhood of $0$. The only common zero of *all* these functions is $0$, but they form a proper subset of $I_0$ -- for example $f(x)=x$ is not there.

There are also ideals that are not defined solely by their zero sets. For example, consider the principal ideal generated by $f(x)=x^2$. This is again a proper subset of $I_0$, but the possible zero sets of functions in it are exactly the closed subsets of $[0,1]$ that contain $0$, just as for $I_0$.